# store image src in a js variable so that it can be used to display background image

Tags: javascript

How to store image src of the above image tag in a javascript variable?

```
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

I need the url so I can enter it in here

```
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url(' + imgsrc + ')";
```

and get the background image

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery = .attr('src');
js = .getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation on how and why this should work

Answer (score 0):

you missing quotes

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ imgsrc +"')";
```